# Group UITableView by date without using coredata

Tags: ios, uitableview, date

I have an NSMutableArray with the latest 30 days records fetched from a DB.
Each record consists of a string and a creation date.

Now I want those records to feed an UITableView that will have a section for each different day and  one cell per section simply showing how many records exist for each day.

Well, it's been hours of thinking and I'm not able yet to figure out how to do it. All the questions I've found on stackoverflow are related to core data, but I don't use it in my app.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your data according to date. Then you can store grouped array on a dictionary and the key will be the date and this key will be your table header and the value will be the list of data at that date. I hope you got this approach.

Comment: I don't know how to group by date, and I've never used dictionaries, so an example would be great.

Comment: to group by date you need to iterate through the array, if the date are not same you need to separate the records on other other array and store them on dictionary. You will find example about dictionary here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Dictionary_Objects

Comment: I recommend to use `NSDateComponents` instead of NSDate as keys in the dictionary.

Comment: I meant by date is string value of nsdate, why you recommend NSDateComponents ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//after fetching data,write below code<br>
int cArray[30]; //create it as global array.cArray stores number of records that fall in particular date. if cArray[j]=10, it means for j'th date, there are 10 records.

// initialise all to zero.

for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
    cArray[i]=0;
}
NSArray *myArray;// my array stores your records.
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Record *rec = (Record*)obj;
    cArray[(int)(rec.creationDate)]++;
}];
```

And later you can use cArray to show number of records that fall in a particular date.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented my data model similar to this case. I have an array of the `NSDateComponents` for each day and have a dictionary which keys is the date components that is stored in the array and values is the arrays that is store the data for each day. This approach is working pretty well for me.